# How to remove unwanted sections theme customize area?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I don't really need **some sections** in WordPress Apperience customize area.

[image]

For example, **i want to remove**, colors, and static page options sections in this area ?

How can i do ? Is that possible ?

P.S:

I just want to use, header image and Site Title & Tagline sections.

here is my code for header image option area.

```
$homepage_image = array(
    'width'         => 1900,
    'height'        => 872,
    'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/home-bg.jpg',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $homepage_image );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `$wp_customize->remove_section('nav');` you will get a php Notice. Check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_loaded_components
and
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/250368/97324

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to remove this, but you will need to just edit the customizer.php file in your themes directory. Could you give me some background info on why you need to disable this. Maybe, we can find you a better solution. Also, check out the codex on the Theme Customizer [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API)

Comment: i check the WordPress codex page but there is no tip about this. Also, i don't have any costomize.php in my theme folder. I just added my functon lines, into the my functions.php file, in my first post.

Comment: just found the sulation 

`$wp_customize->remove_section('nav');
    $wp_customize->remove_section('static_front_page');`